# How do I create a table with a filter that filters on the server in webMethods CAF?

Tags: jsf, webmethods, webmethods-caf

I have a web service that populates a table, using a SelectableListTableContentProvider, which works nicely.

However if I add a Filter Input control to the table, all it does is filter on the current table contents on the client side, ie if I'm on page 1 of 10 of the table, it doesn't go and check all values, just the ones on page 1.

How do I make a Filter Input control filter on all the values that the web service can return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you do it:

1. Create as you say a `SelectableListTableContentProvider` (let's call it `myDataProvider`), and make sure all that stuff works between the web service, the provider and the screen. This is just in case there's a mistake here and the next bit then won't work properly. Just make sure it looks normal, pages through the data properly, etc. Give the table a nice, descriptive ID.
2. Add a Filter Input control to the screen. Set its `For` property to be the ID of the table.
3. Go into your code and change `myDataProvider`'s type from `SelectableListTableContentProvider` to `FilterableSelectableListTableContentProvider`. You will need to do it in the variable's declaration:

   ```
   SelectableListTableContentProvider myDataProvider;
   ```

   In two places in its getter:

   ```
   public com.webmethods.caf.faces.data.object.SelectableListTableContentProvider getMyDataProvider()  {
     if (myDataProvider == null) {
       metadataOrganisationProvider = (com.webmethods.caf.faces.data.object.SelectableListTableContentProvider)resolveExpression("#{myDataProvider}");
     }

     resolveDataBinding(MYDATAPROVIDER_PROPERTY_BINDINGS, myDataProvider, "myDataProvider", false, false);
     return myDataProvider;
   }
   ```

   AND in the managed bean config in `faces-config.xml`:

   ```
   <managed-bean>
   <managed-bean-name>myDataProvider</managed-bean-name>
   <managed-bean-class>com.webmethods.caf.faces.data.object.SelectableListTableContentProvider</managed-bean-class>
   <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
   <managed-property>
       <description>Specifies whether the session bean expires when the pageflow is out of scope</description>
       <display-name>Expire With Page Flow</display-name>
       <property-name>expireWithPageFlow</property-name>
       <property-class>java.lang.Boolean</property-class>
       <value>true</value>
   </managed-property>
   ```

   In each example I'm showing what it looks like *before* it's changed. Just add the word `Filter` before `SelectableListTableContentProvider`.

   Now you have a filterable content provider.
4. The screen will error at this point if you try to run it. Why? Good question. Why, Software AG? Why don't you provide a sensible default? Why do we have to pick which field to filter on, unlike the out of the box behaviour of the client-side Filter Input control, which just defaults to filtering on everything?

   Anyway. Open up the filterable provider in the Bindings pane. It looks a bit weird, because I don't think they've configured this as well as they could. Pick the `Row Filter Value Binding` property (its icon is a * in a box; don't know why it's not a string) and set its Data Binding property to be the *Controls Scoped Variable* of the correct field in the provider.

   That doesn't make sense? Okay, I'll break it down:

   1. Click on your table in the WYSIWYG view thing. Not a row in the table, the whole table. Make sure this stays selected and you don't accidentally unselect it.
   2. Click on the `Row Filter Value Binding` under your provider in the Bindings pane.
   3. In the Properties pane, go to the Data Binding tab and click the `#{...}` button to browse for the value you want.
   4. In the popup that opens, scroll to the top and open up the `Controls Scoped Variables` section. If this doesn't exist, go back to a) and do it properly :)
   5. Pick the value you want to filter on.
   6. Hit okay. The field will be bound to something that looks like this:

      ```
      #{result.nameOfFieldToFilterOn}
      ```

Deploy and enjoy :)